# Connect to to AWS Athena using the AWS SSO from dBeaver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbeaver, aws-sso

I am trying to connect to AWS Athena from the dbeaver. Documentation is saying that I can do that using the AWS SSO https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/AWS-SSO.

I went through all options and was not able to find such a configuration. I am using version 21.3.5.

Can anyone help me where do I find such a configuration?[image]

Comment: Looks like browser SSO option for some reason do not exist for Athena but exists for example for AWS Snowflake.

Answer (score 6):

From the first screen shot, it appears you are using the Community Edition. True SSO is not supported for CE, but you can make it work. Use AWS's SSO awsapps start page and select the account / role you wish to use. Select 'Command line or programmatic access'. Choose option 2) 'Add a profile to your AWS Credentials file' and click to copy the text. Paste this text into your ~/.aws/credentials file. Now copy the first line of the credentials file but leave out the brackets '[]'. Edit the connection in DBeaver. Under driver properties paste the value for 'AwsCredentialsProviderArguments'. Then for 'AwsCredentialsProviderClass' set the value to 'com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider'. The output S3 bucket and region should be set to what you need. Leave user and password blank and check 'save password locally'. The connection should work now. Note: this is only a session token and will time out after several hours. Just repeat and update the contents in the credentials file to update the session token. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you use the Community version. However, AWS SSO is only available in the commercial versions of DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Please ignore this answer if you are interested on the AWS SSO authentication using Athena with DBeaver. Thanks to @rholdberh I just noticed it.

This answer assumes you have an AWS key/secret pair, not SSO credentials.

---

Perhaps is that now supported?

I am successfully using the Community version:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

As requested by @rholdberh in the comments, the Driver properties, where I **only added the Workgroup**. Nothing else:

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please make a screenshot of your driver properties or connection details to  check how sso is setup?

Comment: My bad @rholdberh I just noticed you explicitly mentioned the SSO authentication. I updated my answer according.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking into this, I was able to make a custom JAR driver work for my AWS SSO configuration.

Mentioned here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/3918#issuecomment-1207615519
Clone the repository here: https://github.com/neitomic/simba-athena-driver-sso-support

I followed the installation instructions in the JAR repo and it worked like a charm.

I'm on a Windows PC, so relied on my Windows Subsystem for Linux installation to install `maven` and build the JAR.